# C++ macro with variable number of parameters

Tags: c++

I need a macro which uses std::cout in case of only one parameter, or better said in case of explicit stream and uses printf in case of more than one parameter. Below is the code I tried.

**EDIT:** the rest of the original text below is pointless based on @n. m. will see y'all on Reddit comment below. So do not bother to read it. I just need a suggestion how to accomplish given task.

Crazy thing is that when I comment out `// LOG("test0" << "test1");` for the remaining two macro calls code will compile and produce expected results despite of a fact that when I hover a mouse over the macro call visual studio shows me a bubble how macro going to be expanded and I clearly see that it expands to something like: `std::cout << "test1 -> %d\n", 7 << ...` which is obiously not valid c++ code. On the other hand when I uncomment `LOG("test0" << "test1");` I get error.

However when I now comment out the last two macro calls + delete line `printf(__VA_ARGS__);` I get the expected result for the first macro call...

```cpp
#define LOG(...) \
{ \
    const std::string test(#__VA_ARGS__); \
    if (test.find("<<") != std::string::npos) std::cout << __VA_ARGS__ << '\n'; \
    else \
    { \
        puts(__FUNCTION__); \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
}

int main()
{
    LOG("test0" << "test1");
    LOG("test1 -> %d\n", 7);
    LOG("test2 -> %d %d\n", 4, 5);
}
```

Comment: "which is obiously not valid c++ code" It is perfectly valid C++ code. It may not do what you think it does, but it doesn't really matter because it is behind an effective `if(false)`. On the other hand `printf("test0" << "test1")` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: I recommend you not try to fake function overloading using macros.  Also, mixing calls to cout and printf are going to give you problems with buffering, even if you get the macro to work.  What problem are you trying to address with this sort of macro?

Comment: @user1806566 I just need to refactor the 20+ years old code in the way as simple as possible, otherwise I would need to refactor all the printf calls to std::cout style calls...

Comment: "just need to refactor the 20+ years old code" Then perhaps ask a question about this problem, instead of creating an XY problem. Why do you need to refactor? How does the code look like today? How do you want it to look?

Comment: @n. m. will see y'all on Reddit it is just a toy example to be not very long. printf here represent custom logging function which takes printf style parameters. I want to extend its functionality by adding this `puts(__FUNCTION__);` Also I want to add some indentation to capture hierarchy of function calls. We simply have some old style logging functions based on printf and some newer logging functions based on std::cout style. Enwrap these two to macro seems to me as the simplest approach.

Comment: Have a look at https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html (or std::format in C++20).  That should be a superset of anything you would do with cout or with printf.  In particular, it lets you print printf-style arguments to an ostream, which sounds like what would solve your problem.

Comment: @user1806566 as I wrote in one of my previous comment. It is 20+ old code...we compile it with C++14. Unfortunately C++20 is not an option for me in this case.

Comment: libfmt works on C++11 and up.  Much of it was incorporated into the standard in C++20, but the standalone library should work for you.

Comment: @user1806566 in that case I definitely going to check that. Thank you!

Comment: I would argue that printf-style logging is actually superior (surpassed only by libfmt). `std::cout` is stateful, so you either need to carefully reset the state at the call site, or at every call inside of the logger. Also the API is much more verbose. The only issue with `printf` is the lack of type checking, which compilers (at least GCC and Clang) conveniently have extensions for.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `LOG` macro call, the macro expansion will look something like this:

```
//NOTE: __VA_ARGS__ is "test0" << "test1"
const std::string test("\"test0\" << \"test1\"");
if (test.find("<<") != std::string::npos) std::cout << "test0" << "test1";
else
{
    puts("main");
    printf("test0" << "test1");
}
```

The error is with the `printf` statement. You cannot use the binary `<<` operator on two C-style strings. This is reflected in the error (at least, the one I got on my compiler): `invalid operands of types 'const char [6]' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator<<'`.

As to how to achieve what you want, unless there's a way to selectively remove C code at runtime, I'm not sure it's possible.